# ado.net transaction rollbacked without any .net error

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

transaction getting rollbacked sometimes, even though there is no error in code.

will ado.net rollback when dbconnectin is lost or fail? it happens only in specific machines time to time.

[image]

```
  using (var dbTransactionManager = new DBTransactionManager())
        {
            try
            {

               //Insert statatement 1

               //Insert statatement 1 //after this statement, transaction is rollbacked, rest of the below statements run without transaction. this doesn't happen always.


               //Insert statatement 1

               //Insert statatement 1

               //Insert statatement 1




                dbTransactionManager.Commit();
                transactionClosed = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                //this never called.
                if (transactionClosed == false)
                {    
                    dbTransactionManager.RollBack();
                }

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You appear to have omitted the SQL statements, which are really important here.

Comment: I looked at the MSDN c# source code.  It looks like a transaction is created for a query.  The beginning of the transaction Rollback is called to capture the rollback state.  Then in the dispose method of the transaction a test is performed to check if connection = null.  If the connection is null then a Rollback is performed.

Comment: @jdweng, yes your point is very valid. and found the place where connection is closed. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ADO.NET is performing an rollback if a connection is null. As jdweng pointed out in his comment, in the `dispose` method of the transaction a test is performed to check if `connection == null`. If it is `null`, the transaction rollback will be performed.

Comment: Thanks, found the rootcause. In some case, connection is closed and new connection is opened in child methods.